# bitnami svn setup

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, bitnami

I have an AWS instance using the Bitnami SVN install.  I hoped this would make setting up source control easy but I'm struggling in the basic configuration.  I tried following these directions:
http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Subversion#How_to_start_with_Subversion_in_Amazon_EC2.3f

- opened up port 3690
- edited  /opt/bitnami/repository/conf/svnserve.conf for user permissions
- added passwords in /opt/bitnami/repository/conf/passwd
- restarted svn with `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart subversion`

However this is where I get stuck.  Now I want to download the repo to my PC, and get this to play nice with Eclipse (not even there yet) so that I can store on the server the code that I have locally.  But I can't figure out how to sync with my PC.  I installed Tortoise SVN, I right click on a folder and select SVN Repo-browser, and I try to connect to `http://ec2-###-##-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com/subversion/` but I don't see anything there.  I tried to add a test file, and I can't seem to commit it.  I get

Commit failed (details follow):
The POST request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line
 3: not well-formed (invalid token) (/subversion/!svn/me)

What am I missing?

Also, as a side, is subversion the default repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access subversion with svn or with http. If you want to connect using http then you don't need to open port 3690 or modify the svnserve.conf for user authentication.

For http access:

- add passwords in /opt/bitnami/repository/conf/passwd
- configure apache to use basic authentication (edit the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file and add the Authxx directives in the location section)

```
DAV svn    
SVNPath "/path/to/subversion/repository"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"
AuthUserFile /opt/btinami/subversion/users.passwd
Require valid-user
```

- Restart apache `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`
- Connect using `http://ec2-###-##-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com/subversion`

For svn access:

- open up port 3690
- edit `/opt/bitnami/repository/conf/svnserve.conf` for user permissions
- restart svn with `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart subversion`
- Connect using the string svn://path/to/your/repository

Comment: Yes, I did steps 1-3 for SVN access as I noted.  I'm struggling with the connection part.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: There is not much to elaborate. If you are inside the machine, can you conntect to the repository? Your using http:// string or svn:// for connecting? how did you open the port?

Comment: I opened up the port using Amazon AWS management console.  I am not sure about your other questions.  This is where I am lost.  I really would like to know, once I get to step 3, exactly what needs to be done to sync my PC with the repository.  How do I connect?  How can I make sure the repo is up?  Based on your replies, I think there is probably something simple I am missing here but I am just not sure what.

Comment: "Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://opt/bitnami/repository' Unknown hostname 'opt'

Comment: I have double checked the default configuration. First you should have been able to connect using http://ec2-###-##-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com/subversion as the connection string without any change. Just launching the instance and the connect. However you made changes in the configuration but for connecting with svn. In that case the connection string should be: svn://ec2-###-##-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com. If you still have problems and you have not been able to commit anything. I suggest to start a new instance and before changing anything check that you can connect.

Comment: You were right.  The problem was in adding the folder.  Just using `svn://ec2-###-##-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com` resolved my issue.  I knew it was going to be something stupid...