# Not able to connect to SVN repository remotely through Tortoise

Tags: svn, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have set up svn repository on my amazon ec2 server

Here is what I have done

I have installed bitnami on amazon and created svn on server which is accessible through server, but when trying to connect with tortoise I am getting connection time out error

I have also open port no 3690 , in default security group, but still not working

Comment: Port 3690 is svnserve, another option is Apache though, are you using the right one? Which URL are you giving to TSVN? What do the commandline tools say, is it TSVN-specific? Can you access the repository locally, i.e. directly on the server using localhost? Do you have any proxies/firewalls in between your machine and the server that might block traffic?

Comment: I am using following url: svn://ec2-184-72-201-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com, Yes there is firewall, but I have open up port 3690, also yes it is accessible directly on server

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the firewall running on the server is open, but you likely also have to setup your aws security group to allow traffic on that port thru. You can do that thru the aws console

http://cloud-computing.learningtree.com/2010/09/24/understanding-amazon-ec2-security-groups-and-firewalls/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: Can you please ellaborate this line?"You need to make sure the firewall running on the server is open"

Comment: Often people have a firewall running on their ever, if so, those ports will need to be opened or the firewall turned off. Secondarily, aws runs the equivalent of a firewall for you, you need to check that too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this question/answer? [bitnami svn setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590773/bitnami-svn-setup)

If you are using svn access you may need to configure the user permissions. However if you are using the BitNami Subversion AMI or native installer then it is already configure to access using http protocol (url: http://ec2-184-72-201-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com)

You can find more information in the BitNami Wiki: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Subversion.