# Getting the subversion address of a server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, bitnami

I have a question very similar to this: [bitnami svn setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590773/bitnami-svn-setup) but still having trouble solving it.

I currently have an Amazon AWS EC2 instance with the Bitnami WAMP Stack. I manually installed the SVN (not using an AMI) and attempted to create a Subversion repository on the following path:

/opt/bitnami/frameworks/codeigniter

On the server I did the following (according to this file: http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Subversion#How_to_start_with_Subversion_in_Amazon_EC2.3f)

- Open the port 3690
- Set the user permissions (anon-access = read, etc, etc)
- Set the user passwords (harry = harrysecret, etc)
- Configure SVN as daemon (svnserve -d)
- Restarted SVN

On the desktop I installed the Tortoise SVN and did Checkout on the following addresses:

- svn://mysite.com/opt/bitnami/framework/codeigniter
- svn://ec2-##-##-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com
- svn://ec2-##-##-###-###.compute-1.amazonaws.com/subversion
- svn://mysite.com
- svn://mysite.com/repositoryname

And any other combination you could imagine but I'm always getting the error "Unable to connect to repository URL, no repository found in [URL]"

I am able to SVN checkout from other SVN sources.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to get the correct server SVN address easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

It turns out that the "served" directory was wrong. For example to read the repository

> /opt/bitnami/frameworks/codeigniter

The svnserve command is:

> sudo svnserve -d -r /opt/bitnami/frameworks

(-d tells svn should be running on background, -r tells the svn to use the following path)

And then the repository should be available at address:

> svn://website.com/codeigniter

Don't know if changing the path is a good idea or not but it seems to do the job.